# In CSS, granular control over where word wrapping occurs?

Tags: css

TL;DR: Wondering if there's a CSS property that can break content where HTML doesn't naturally:

```
         Baby
Buggy Bumpers
```

instead of

```
Baby Buggy
   Bumpers
```

The only way I can think of to do it is to add `&nbsp;` where you *don't* want the line to break, but I'm working in WordPress, which strips those.

This is to graphically style a site's name on the home page. The site name is part of the nav, so it's inside an `<li>`, using grid layout.

Luckily in my case, setting the width with a dimension that is relative to the font size seems to break the way I want at all viewport widths:

```
.my-brand a {
    width: 16ch;
    text-align: end;
}
```

`white-space: nowrap` and such elements won't work with the "baby buggy bumpers" example because the need is to break after one specific word. Just wondering if there's some way to specify in a way similar to `nth-child(2)`.

Made a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rickmakeitquick/pen/PopLbPL) to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use Javascript and can't add tags in the string like :

```
<div class='string'>
  Baby<span>Buggy Bumpers</span>
</div>
```

It only remain "hacky" CSS solution. There is one using pseudo-elements :

**HTML :**

```
<div class='string'>
  Baby
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.string{
    width: 11ch;
  text-align: end;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.string::after {
    content: "Buggy Bumpers";
    color: red;
display:block ;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Live exemple : https://codepen.io/camillewemajin/pen/JjWzWzN

But that's not really clean for many reasons, like SEO...

Comment: Creative solution, thank you. I wonder if adding a pseudo element with hidden content "buggy bumpers" to the `.string` might resolve the SEO and accessibility problems?

Comment: I think if this were a real world problem, the best solution might be to turn the "logo" into an SVG and add alt text for SEO and accessibility.

Comment: You're totaly right, as your example is a title/short text it's "ok", just don't use this solution for title you absolutly need for google to index, or important content :)